# What would happen if the cathode ray experiment by jj Thompson was done in complete vacuum?

Tags: electrons

[image]
Cathode tube has complete vacuum and potential difference of 10,000. Volts
There is a hole in anode for electrons to pass.

Answer (score 2):

I can't find the details of the equipment J. J. Thomson used, but I believe it did not use a heated electrode i.e. it did not use thermionic emission as the source of the electrons.

In that case the electrons were generated by an [avalanche process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_avalanche) in the gas in the tube. Any stray electrons, for example produced by cosmic rays, were accelerated and collided with gas molecules ionising them and creating more free electrons. These electrons in turn collided with more gas molecules and so on, and the result is a lot of free electrons to form the electron beam.

If the tube were completely evacuated there would be no free electrons and hence no beam. I would guess that J. J. Thomson had to experiment to find the best gas pressure for the avalanche process to create a beam.